# How can I use more than one word as the user input on a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

how do I make it work so that when I have more than one word as the user input? for the percent?

```
@echo off

Title programming test

set /p Heyyya= Type a command:

if %Heyyya% == "stop now" echo Correct

if not %Heyyya% == "stop error" echo sorry

pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

echo Title programming test
set /p Heyyya=Type a command:

if "%Heyyya%"=="stop now" (echo Correct & goto:correct )
if not "%Heyyya%"=="stop error" echo Sorry

:correct

pause >nul
```